# Windows NFS Client Tools Doesn't Follow manage-gids

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, nfs

I am running into an issue with the Windows NFS Client tools, it seems that when I attempt to access a folder on an NFS share that has read permissions for a group that user is member of - but not the users primary group, I get a permission denied error message. Works fine if the AD users primary group is the owner of the folder.

A bit about my environment:

- AD Running on Windows Server 2012 R2
- NFS Server running on CentOS - Connected to the AD domain, **rpc.mountd has  --manage-gids flag enabled - meaning it only requires the UID, it then goes and gets the GIDs.**
- Windows 7 Client connected to the AD domain

For example lets look at the following scenario:

**User1**

Member of the following Groups: a (Primary), b, c

**Folders on NFS**

test1 - Group: a

test2 - Group: b

In my case 'User1' is able to access the test1 directory on the NFS server as their primary group is 'a'. 
They are not able to access the 'test2' directory, even though they are a member of the 'b' group.

This scenario works fine in Linux, User1 can access both test1 and test2 directories as expected.

Im sure it is an issue with my windows NFS client as:
- On the NFS server I see success authentication in the messages log file when I attempt to access the share from windows
- Works as expected in Linux

Anyone got any ideas on why this isn't working?

I've out of options, thought I would try here first before I resort to Samba.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the UNIX groups stored in your AD (RFC 2307)? Are you using SSSD?